# Used System function to open an excel sheet

Tags: c++, windows, excel

I'm using System function `System(mypath/test.xls)` to open and edit an excel sheet in C++ run time. It opens my excel sheet, allows me to edit ans close the same. After closing the excel sheet, the control goes to the code again. Everything works fine unless there is already some other excel sheet opened. If there is some other excel sheet already opened in the machine, I will not able to edit and close so that control goes to code. Can anyone suggest any solutions for this issue.

Comment: Rather than using the `system` call, you might be able to use automation stuff (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/216686?fr=1) via OLE to open your sheet, and then casually poll until the sheet is closed (or maybe you can install hooks to fire when it is closed).

Answer (score 2):

What is happening is your `System(..)` function call is asking the Windows shell to find the application associated with your file (test.xls) , which is Excel. Then if Excel is already running it is asked to open file. If the application is not running, then Windows starts the application for you.

So if the application is not already running and it is started for you it becomes associated with your program as a 'child' process. Therefore your `System(..)` call waits for it to end before continuing. If however Excel is already running then once Windows informs that instance of your desire to open the file test.xls, your call to `System(..)` returns immediately.

You can avoid this by explicitly running the Excel program by giving the full path to the Excel EXE file. And including the /x command line argument and full path to your file. The /x causes Excel to open a new process and then open your file. This new process is a child of your program's so the `System(..)` call will wait..

I'm not familiar with the `System(..)` call (is it like the `system(..)` one?) you may have to provide the switch /x, and path arguments as distinct arguments to this call rather than in one long string. Also there may be options on how your child process is launched, so waiting for it to return may be optional and so forth.